# Bags with balls - Combinatorial Optimization of Probability problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, optimization, discrete-optimization, balls-in-bins

Suppose there are $n$ bags, each one contains various numbers of balls of differing sizes.

A white ball, of certain size, distinct from all other balls in the bags, is thrown into one of the bags, randomly selected with probability $p_{i}$ ( so that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_{i} = 1$).

The probability of picking this white ball, from bag $i$, conditioned on the ball being thrown in that bag $i$, is $c_{i} \in [0,1]$. The probabilities $c_{i}$ may vary from bag to bag, depending on the size and number of other balls there. Note that here the closed interval $[0,1]$ is given for $c_{i}$ as it could be that the white ball is so small compared to the other already present balls in bag $i$, that the chances of picking it out are essentially zero, while on the other extreme, bag $i$ could be empty beforehand.

I have $k$ tries to pick out a white ball from the bags. Here $k \geq n$. I can pick a ball from any of the bags in any order, and I can re-pick a ball from any of the bags as many times as I want (up to maximum $k$ in total). I stop when I first pick out a white ball. After each try that is unsuccessful, I replace the ball in the same bag.

For example, if $n=3$ and $k=6$, a possible sequence of bags I pick from, assuming that I only get a white ball on last attempt (or that I don't get the white ball at all) could be $3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3 $. Another possibility could be $1,1,1,1,1,2$, etc.

My question is: how do I devise a strategy for the number of tries for each bag, so that the probability of me picking out a white ball in $k$ attempts or less is maximised?

Comment: Interesting problem. Is this homework? I doubt that there is closed form general solution. BTW: what matters here (if I understood it right) is not the sequence order of the search, but only how many tries I assign for each bag, right?

Comment: I change a little the notation and statement, hope you are ok. 
BTW, "picking out a white ball by $k-$th attempt" mean in $k$ _or less_ attempts, no?

Comment: You know the $b_i$, is that correct?

Comment: @saulspatz Originally, $c_i$ was given as data, I changed the formulation so it's more natural (but feel free to assume $c_i$ as given, freely)

Comment: My immediate guess would be to start with the smallest bag, and in case of failure, recompute the probability of the ball's being in each bag.  Then always try the bag with the greatest probability.  Not only does that give you the best chance of success on the current draw, it should give you the most information in case of failure.  That is, it should allow you to update the probabilities most effectively.

Comment: I tend to agree with @saulspatz above (except that you should choose the bag with greates $p_i c_i$ ), and then (if you fail) update the a posteriori probalities $p_i$ and repeat.

Comment: I too updated the statement and notation of the question. The reason being is that this question originates from me looking at a real-life problem that I think could be more accurately presented the way it is written now. Therefore I have no clue what the answer should be (closed form or not). @leonbloy

Comment: I don't understand why I would need to update the " a posteriori probabilities $p_{i}$? " These probabilities are already fixed... @leonbloy

Comment: Yes, $c_{i}$ and $p_{i}$ are known @saulspatz

Comment: Suppose $b_1=1$ and you draw from bag one ten times without finding the white ball.  Don't you start to believe that the ball is most likely in another bag?  This is what Bayes' rule is all about.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how Bayes' rule is applied in your example... My understanding of calculating probabilities here is like this. Let $A_{i}$ be event "drawing a white ball from bag $i$. Let $B_{i}$ be event "white ball is thrown in $i$-th bag". Then $P(A_{i}) = P(A_{i}|B_{i})P(B_{i}) = c_{i}p_{i}$. @saulspatz

Comment: Further, suppose $n=3$ and $k=4$. Let $A$ be event "drawing the white ball by 4th attempt". Let my choice of bags be $1,2,3,1$ in this order. Then $$P(A) = c_{1}p_{1} + (1-c_{1}p_{1})c_{2}p_{2} + (1-c_{1}p_{1})(1-c_{2}p_{2})c_{3}p_{3} + (1-c_{1}p_{1})(1-c_{2}p_{2})(1-c_{3}p_{3})c_{1}p_{1}.$$ Is this formula and the one in my previous comment correct? @saulspatz

Comment: No, I was talking about drawing from the first bag $$ times in a row.

Comment: Ok, suppose you withdraw $k$ times from bag $i$. Then the probability would be $P(A) = \sum_{l=0}^{k-1} (1-c_{i}p_{i})^{l} c_{i}p_{i}$. I still don't see how I'd need to "update the probabilities most effectively" @saulspatz

Comment: I assume the answer given by @leonbloy answers your question.  (Anyway, I certainly can't give a better explanation than he did.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is stated as a global optimization (maximize the probability of finding the ball in no more than $k$ attempts), but it seems true (assumed, not proved here [*]) that it's equivalent to iteratively (greedily) maximize the probability of finding the ball in the next attempt.

Let $c_i$ be the probability of finding the white ball when attempting an extraction from bag $i$, conditioned that the white ball is there. This doesn't change.

Let $X$ be the position of the ball, and let $p_i=P(X=i)$ be the probability of the white ball being in bag $i$. Initially, this is a given priori. At each (failed) attempt, we'll update this to reflect the a posteriori probability.

Let $F_i$ be the event that we failed to get the white ball, given we tried bag $i$.

To maximize the probability of success on the first attempt, is to mimimize $F_i$. But $P(F_i) = 1 - d_i$, where $d_i = p_i \, c_i$.  Hence, denoting by $s$ the selected bag, we have $s= \mathrm{argmax}_i \, d_i$ . And the probability of success is $d_s=\max_i(d_i)$

Given that we failed, the probabilities $p_i$ are updated via Bayes thus:

For $i=s$:

$$ 
\begin{align}
p'_s=P(X=s \mid F_s)&=\frac{P(F_s\mid  X=s)P(X=s)}{P(F_s\mid  X=s)P(X=s)+P(F_s\mid  x\ne s)P(X\ne s)}\\
&=\frac{(1-c_s)p_s}{(1-c_s)p_s + (1-p_s)}\\
&=\frac{p_s-d_s}{1-d_s} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

For $i\ne s$ we first compute

$$
\begin{align}
 P(F_s \mid X \ne i) &=  P(F_s \mid X=s, X \ne i  ) P(X=s\mid X \ne i) + P(F_s \mid X \ne s, X \ne i)P(X=s\mid X \ne i) \\
&= (1-c_s) \frac{p_s}{1-p_i} + 1\times (1 - \frac{p_s}{1-p_i}) \\
&= \frac{1}{1-p_i}(1- p_i - c_s p_s) 
\end{align}
$$

And then

$$
\begin{align}
p'_i =P(X=i \mid F_s)&= \frac{P(F_s\mid  X=i)P(X=i)}{P(F_s\mid  X=i)P(X=i)+P(F_s\mid  X\ne i)P(X\ne i)} \\
&= \frac{ 1\times p_i }{1\times p_i + \frac{1}{1-p_i}(1- p_i - c_s p_s) (1-p_i) }\\
&=\frac{p_i}{1 -c_s p_s} = \frac{p_i}{1 - d_s} \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

With $(1)$ and $(2)$ together we update the probabilites $p_i$ and $d_i$ and repeat.

An example with $n=4$ bags and $k=5$

[image]

In yellow, the selected bags in each attempt. In orange, the probability of having found the white ball at that point.

---

Update: For large $k$ , we could attempt a maximization using (abusing) Lagrange multipliers. 
<s>I'll spare the details (ask if you want them), but the result is</s>

Let $k_i$ denote how many times bag $i$ was selected, in $k$ extractions (hence $\sum_{i=1}^n k_i=k$)
Then the probability of failure is

$$\begin{align} P(F; k_1,k_2 \cdots k_n) &= \sum_{i=1}^n P(X=i)   P(F \mid X=i; k_1,k_2 \cdots k_n) \\
&=  \sum_{i=1}^n p_i (1 - c_i)^{k_i}
=  \sum_{i=1}^n p_i e^{ -a_i \,k_i}
\end{align}$$

where  $a_i = - \log(1-c_i)$

We wish to minimize this function of the multivariate variable $(k_1,k_2 \cdots k_n)$ subject to the condition $C(k_1,k_2 \cdots k_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n k_i-k =0$

Lagrange multipliers would be apt for this.. except that our variables are not real but integer. Anyway, abusing the method, equating the derivative to zero gives:

$$ - p_i a_i e^{ -a_i \,k_i} + \lambda = 0 \hskip{1 cm} i=1,2 \dots n$$

which can be written as

$$k_i = \frac{\log(\, p_i a_i) + \beta }{a_i} \tag 3$$

where and $\beta$ is a number that is obtained by solving (numerically, it seems) the constraint $\sum k_i = k$ together with $(3)$.

Of course, $(3)$ gives non integer numbers, we should expect that rounding to the nearest integers (always respecting the sum restriction) gives at least a good approximation to the optimal value.

For example, with $k=10$ and same $p_i$, $c_i$ as in the example above, I get $k_i=(4.198, 2.941, 1.538, 1.330)$ while the optimal values are $(4, 3, 2 ,1)$.

Comment: +1 This is what I meant.  I see now that I sloppily said, "the bag with the greatest probability", when I meant to say "the bag that gives the greatest probability of success on the next draw".

Comment: Ok, so  I see from your answer that the crucial point is that the events "failure on the $i$ - th try"   and "success on the $(i+1)$ - th try" are NOT independent, right?  @leonbloy

Comment: I wouldn't say that. The crucial point is that "$F_s=$ failure when choosing bag $s$" and "$p(X=i)=$ probability of bag $i$ having the white ball" are not independent. Hence $p(X=i | F_s) \ne P(X = i)$  @saulspatz explained this in the comments

Comment: @Alex Done.....

Comment: Thanks - I have verified the calculation before you posted the updated answer (hence my deleted comment). I am thinking, would there be any further way to further optimise the solution in terms of $k$? Initially I thought it might be some variant of the Knapsack problem...I'd be very interested to see some more details of your Lagrange multipler approach? @leonbloy

Comment: I added the Lagrange multipler explanation

Comment: In your Lagrange multiplier explanation, why isn't $p_{i}$ updated at every step? Your calculation seems to contradict what you wrote earlier that $p_{i}$ must be updated... @leonbloy

Comment: @Alex The Lagrange multipliers approach is not iterative, it looks at the global result.

Comment: I am confused more than ever. In your formula $P(F;k_{1},,..k_{n}) = \sum P(X=i)P(F|X_{i}=i;k_{1},...)$ you always take $P(X=i) =p_{i}$ as it is given apriori, however earlier you state that $p_{i}$ must change depending on outcome of previous search ?  @leonbloy

Comment: @leonbloy , I think now I understand why $p_{i}$ are not updated in your Lagrange approach. I have two questions:  1) The reason why you formulated your solution in terms of minimisation of "failure" is because if you tried to maximise "success" instead, you would not obtain such a simple formula for probability, right? Because for success, you'd have to account for the fact that you may not "run through" all $k_{i}$'s till you manage to extract the white ball? And b) why do you actually need Lagrange multipliers -  isn't there any "knapsack type" algorithm to solve it?